# Could not find Android partner Api in Google developer console for enabling?

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I could not find option for enabling **Android Partner API** in Google Developer Console API list.

Any help on this will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Partner API is deprecated from November 26th, 2018 [1]. Android partners should use the Compatibility Service for all API interactions [2].

---

[1] https://developers.google.com/android-partner/guide/apfe-api

[2] https://developers.google.com/android-partner/guide/compatibility